# Qt's default threads

Tags: c++, macos, qt

When I start a new Qt application with a minimal amount of code and run it, I see that there are a number of threads running, which at a minimum is 2 and can be as many as 5. It usually settles at 2, until I drag the window around, at which time I see up to 4 threads running.

This is all the code I'm using: -

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Can someone explain why there are different threads and what they're likely to be for? Originally I expected just one, but wouldn't be surprised if a second was used for handling messages. However, what could account for the other threads?

Comment: All user code is executed in the main thread by default. There may be other threads, but they are used by Qt's internal implementation or by debugger. When you write normal applications, you don't need to think about other threads. All your code related to events, signals or slots will be executed in the main thread unless you create new user threads using Qt API.

Comment: @tebe, as you can see from the code in the question, there are no timers in use. All the code you see is there.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, "When you write normal applications" - my main application isn't what would be called 'normal', so I'm creating a test application to see what's happening with threads, but wasn't expecting to see 5 threads from such minimal code.

Comment: If you came to worry about the number of threads QT uses internally, you are doing something wrong. if for no other reason, then because it is internal implementation, and can be changed at any time. Unless, of course, you want to know this out of curiosity...

Comment: @yosim, I'm not worried; this is research and interestingly, no-one has been able to answer this yet.

Comment: @tebe: "if you use a QTimer::singleShot for a delayed slot-call I believe Qt spawns a thread to count down." This is a fantasy. Please stop making stuff up.

Comment: Comment removed, major confusion on my side with a custom implementation. Sry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see now that you're asking out of curiosity in opposite to practical problems. Let's do some research.

I've tried to run your program on Qt 5.1 with MSVC toolkit on Windows. I configured the debugger to break on thread creation. I saw that 4 additional threads have been spawned. 3 of them were caused by Qt calling `RegisterDragDrop` native Windows function. When I skip `QWindowsWindow::registerDropSite` execution, these 3 threads are not created. There is no explanation about the threads even in the `RegisterDragDrop` documentation, not to say about Qt documentation.  Obviously this fact can vary when using different OSs or Qt versions (for example you can build Qt without drag-n-drop support). The only way you can find out why the threads were created for you is an experiment. I think OS X also has some surprises for you.

The 4th thread is a mystery to me: debugger cannot detect when it is started. Maybe this thread is caused by debugger somehow.

As I expected, @tebe was wrong saying that Qt spawns additional threads for QTimer processing (I don't know about all cases, but in my case this is surely incorrect). QTimer uses the event loop of current thread.

Comment: Thanks Pavel for taking the time to look into this. It's all interesting stuff and the drag-drop does correlate with what I see, though as you say, there's still a thread that doesn't stop in the debugger. I wouldn't expect that the timers run on different threads, else it would mean that the GUI could be freed from being blocked by using timers, rather than having to create extra threads. I'll continue looking into this and see how OSX compares.