# QThread: "Destroyed while thread is still running" in a single threaded program

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qapplication

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   QApplicaiton app(argc, argv);

   // parsing other arguments of argc,argv

   return app.exec();
}
```

My problem is the following:
Function may be returned during parsing other arguments (without reaching app.exec()) and when QApplication object is deleted I am getting following error message `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. As a possible solution I am trying to create QApplication after argument parsing is done.

I have tried `app.thread()->quit();` before return statement but it doesn't help.

When QApplication object is created it removes specific arguments (-style, etc.) from argc, argv.

Is it possible to get them from argc, argv manually without creating QApplication object?

It is weird that in a single threaded program I am getting `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running` error.

The best "solution" I have found so far is to create QApplication dynamically and not to delete it. The memory leak is not an issue because it is leaked just before program exits.

Comment: Will you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry but I can't. On MCVE error message disappears. Problem is related to our build system and one specific platform. Maybe wrong library is linked. I just need workaround to suppress wrong error message.

Comment: @Ashot Some Qt classes create threads behind the scenes (such as `QFileSystemWatcher` and some of the networking classes), so your application may not necessarily be single threaded.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616585/qts-default-threads) may be of interest here.